# Editing password-protected Excel binary (*.xls) file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2007, npoi

I need to open and edit a password protected Excel binary file (*.xls) using C#, but every library I've tried so far seems to have trouble with this.

Note that:

- I can't convert the Excel file, it needs to be a *.xls
- I do have the password to the file.

What I've tried so far:

- [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) which seems to work fine with OpenXML Excel files, but doesn't support binary files at all.
- [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) Supports Excel binary files, can protect them, but not encrypt or decrypt them. Encryption works for OpenXML files, but not protection. Rather patchy library.
- [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/) Can open and read password protected files, but not manipulate or save them.

To make this even more difficult, there seems to be numerous questions related to this here on SO and around the web, but they either focus on a certain library, or are not suitable for C# because of different libraries that don't exist there.

Does anyone have experience with this? Or maybe struggled with this themselves and actually found a solution?

Comment: Microsoft has published the file format for those files (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14565).  The only reason they were published was to satisfy some court back in the "breakup the Microsoft monopoly" days.  The various formats are based on the old COM storage and stream formats and are *extremely* hard to groc.  The XLS format was superseded by the Open XML stuff more than 10 years ago (with Office 2007).  Good luck with getting this to work - you were handed a terrible set of specs.

Comment: Can you use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?